# Deploy on heroku with nodeJs/Adonis: I'm getting 503 Status - Service Unvailable

Tags: node.js, heroku, adonis.js

I'm trying to make a deploy using heroku, but when i make a get in the URL/route i get:

> Status: 503 Service Unvailable.

My application is only api;

My ProcFile:

release: ENV_SILENT=true node ace migration:run --force
web: ENV_SILENT=true npm start

When i run `git push heroku master` i get:

> Enumerating objects: 5, done. Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads Compressing objects: 100%
>   (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 145.00 KiB/s,
>   done. Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source
>   files... done. remote: Building source: remote:  remote: ----->
>   Node.js app detected remote:         remote: -----> Creating runtime
>   environment remote: remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error remote:
>   NODE_ENV=production remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true remote:
>   NODE_VERBOSE=false remote: remote: -----> Installing binaries remote: 
>   engines.node (package.json):  10.16.3 remote:        engines.npm
>   (package.json):   unspecified (use default) remote: remote:
>   Resolving node version 10.16.3... remote:        Downloading and
>   installing node 10.16.3... remote:        Using default npm version:
>   6.9.0 remote:         remote: -----> Restoring cache remote:        - node_modules remote:         remote: -----> Installing dependencies
>   remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>   remote:        added 137 packages from 91 contributors and audited
>   5288 packages in 10.225s remote:        found 2 high severity
>   vulnerabilities remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or
>   `npm audit` for details remote:         remote: -----> Build remote:
>   remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies remote:        removed 137
>   packages and audited 4976 packages in 5.253s remote:        found 2
>   high severity vulnerabilities remote:          run `npm audit fix` to
>   fix them, or `npm audit` for details remote:         remote: ----->
>   Caching build remote:        - node_modules remote:         remote:
>   -----> Build succeeded! remote: -----> Discovering process types remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web remote: remote:
>   -----> Compressing... remote:        Done: 26M remote: -----> Launching... remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release
>   will not be available until the command succeeds. remote:
>   Released v20 remote:        https://xxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to
>   Heroku remote: remote: Verifying deploy... done. remote: Running
>   release command... remote: remote: Nothing to migrate remote: Waiting
>   for release.... done. To https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git
>   xxx..62bc4e0  master -> master

I try differents routes that work in localhost, but when i try in heroku i get 503.

Comment: Try to change HOST to 0.0.0.0 (In your Heroku environment variables). It solves your problem.?

Comment: put your logs . type command ```heroku logs -t ``` in cmd. this give you a log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved on https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/deploy-on-heroku-im-receiving-503-service-unvailable/5069

**Answer** : Try to change `HOST` to `0.0.0.0` (In your Heroku environment variables)